# yeoman angular generator - generated index.html

Tags: yeoman, bower

Last day I was in process of updating `Angular` library in my project from `1.0.7` to `1.2.6`, to do this, I updated my `yeoman` generator and generated application again.

After this, I started browsing generated files to get hang of the changes and I noticed something new in `index.html` file.

```
    <!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

I know that `<!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->` and `<!-- endbuild -->` comments are used by `grunt-usemin` task, but what is the purpose of `<!-- bower:js -->` and `<!-- endbower -->`? I can't find any mention of it in `bower` documentation posted on main page.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's [grunt-bower-install](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-bower-install), which was [added to v0.7.0](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v070-2013-12-20) of the Angular generator.

Initially, when you scaffolded the application, it automatically wired up your Bower packages to your `index.html` file. Going forward, after installing or un-installing a Bower package, you can run `grunt bower-install` to update the references inside of your `<!-- bower:* -->...<!-- endbower -->` blocks.

Also, notice in the `<head>` section, there is a `<!-- bower:css -->` block, which will reference your Bower packages' CSS files.

*Update - 8/7/2014*

If `grunt-bower-install` doesn't work try(in order):
`grunt wiredep`, `grunt bower-install`, `grunt bowerInstall`

Make sure to bower install  --save to add it to bower.json as a dependency.

Comment: Just a note, maybe it's different in newer versions but the command is `grunt bowerInstall`

Comment: This answer is out of date.  I wasted about an hour trying to get `grunt bower-install` to work only to finally learn from a github issue that nowadays it seems to be `grunt bowerInstall`.

Comment: Brian, depending on the version you're using, it will be grunt bower-install, grunt bowerInstall, or now, since it was renamed, grunt wiredep. Sorry this tripped you up, but the answer to this question is still to run grunt bower-install, as that is the version that is being used with this project. As always, when things don't work, check with the appropriate documentation: in this case, simply reading up on Grunt tasks should have familiarized you with how tasks are configured, and you could have figured out which command to run from there. Thanks for looking out for fellow devs :)

Comment: `grunt wiredep` for all new yeoman/grunt/bower recruits.  Happy scaffolding!

Comment: @BrianTingle that's why I always read the comments of the answers as well, esp the one above yours ;)

Comment: yes, I read that -- but I was using the newest version of yeomen, the answer above suggested that was the older incantation.  I tried to edit the answer, but my edit was rejected so I added a comment so that if I came back to this again (I often find myself coming back to the same questions over and over) I would know the comment above mine was misleading w/r/t older vs. newer versions.

Comment: @Stephen I'm having a quite simular question. Do I have to repeat these HTML comments manually in each file, or do I add all HTML-files to the Grunt task and let it do it's magic?

Comment: @JN11 - you'll have to add those in manually. That's a small trade off for all the magic wiredep will do :)

Comment: @Stephen - do you think is there something similar for Gulp?

Comment: Adrian, you can use wiredep directly. See https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep#build-chain-integration