# Gruntfile to build Bower components from HTML src markup

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, bower

I've used grunt markup within HTML files that need JS and CSS built, but grunt fails to build them unless they are essentially hardcoded into my Gruntfile.

Is the syntax I'm using wrong? I think there maybe an issue within my Gruntfile - I don't want to declare the whole of bower_components buildable within it, I want the Grunt to work out what to build from the HTML markup.

TL;DR: The HTML markup I've used for bower_components isn't compiling to the compiled CSS and JS file. They have to be included separately.

If you need any more information please let me know:

Example JS HTML markup

```
<!-- build:js js/compiled.min.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/add-to-homescreen/src/addtohomescreen.min.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<script src="js/woweLibrary.js"></script>
<!-- /build -->
```

Example CSS HTML markup

```
<!-- build:css css/compiled.min.css -->
<!-- bower:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<!-- endbower -->
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- /build -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/addtohomescreen.css" />
```

Gruntfile

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap's Gruntfile
 * http://getbootstrap.com
 * Copyright 2013-2015 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

module.exports = function (grunt) {
  'use strict';

  // Force use of Unix newlines
  grunt.util.linefeed = '\n';

  RegExp.quote = function (string) {
    return string.replace(/[-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
  };

  var fs = require('fs');
  var path = require('path');
  var npmShrinkwrap = require('npm-shrinkwrap');
  var generateGlyphiconsData = require('./grunt/bs-glyphicons-data-generator.js');
  var BsLessdocParser = require('./grunt/bs-lessdoc-parser.js');
  var getLessVarsData = function () {
    var filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'less/variables.less');
    var fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath, { encoding: 'utf8' });
    var parser = new BsLessdocParser(fileContent);
    return { sections: parser.parseFile() };
  };
  var generateRawFiles = require('./grunt/bs-raw-files-generator.js');
  var generateCommonJSModule = require('./grunt/bs-commonjs-generator.js');
  var configBridge = grunt.file.readJSON('./grunt/configBridge.json', { encoding: 'utf8' });

  Object.keys(configBridge.paths).forEach(function (key) {
    configBridge.paths[key].forEach(function (val, i, arr) {
      arr[i] = path.join('./docs/assets', val);
    });
  });

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Metadata.
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    banner: '/*!\n' +
            ' * Bootstrap v<%= pkg.version %> (<%= pkg.homepage %>)\n' +
            ' * Copyright 2011-<%= grunt.template.today("yyyy") %> <%= pkg.author %>\n' +
            ' * Licensed under <%= pkg.license.type %> (<%= pkg.license.url %>)\n' +
            ' */\n',
    jqueryCheck: configBridge.config.jqueryCheck.join('\n'),
    jqueryVersionCheck: configBridge.config.jqueryVersionCheck.join('\n'),

    // Task configuration.
    clean: {
      dist: 'dist',
      docs: 'docs/dist'
    },

    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: 'js/.jshintrc'
      },
      grunt: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'grunt/.jshintrc'
        },
        src: ['Gruntfile.js', 'grunt/*.js']
      },
      core: {
        src: 'js/*.js'
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'js/tests/unit/.jshintrc'
        },
        src: 'js/tests/unit/*.js'
      },
      assets: {
        src: ['docs/assets/js/src/*.js', 'docs/assets/js/*.js', '!docs/assets/js/*.min.js']
      }
    },

    jscs: {
      options: {
        config: 'js/.jscsrc'
      },
      grunt: {
        src: '<%= jshint.grunt.src %>'
      },
      core: {
        src: '<%= jshint.core.src %>'
      },
      test: {
        src: '<%= jshint.test.src %>'
      },
      assets: {
        options: {
          requireCamelCaseOrUpperCaseIdentifiers: null
        },
        src: '<%= jshint.assets.src %>'
      }
    },

    concat: {
      options: {
        banner: '<%= banner %>\n<%= jqueryCheck %>\n<%= jqueryVersionCheck %>',
        stripBanners: false
      },
      bootstrap: {
        src: [
          'js/transition.js',
          'js/alert.js',
          'js/button.js',
          'js/carousel.js',
          'js/collapse.js',
          'js/dropdown.js',
          'js/modal.js',
          'js/tooltip.js',
          'js/popover.js',
          'js/scrollspy.js',
          'js/tab.js',
          'js/affix.js'
        ],
        dest: 'dist/js/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
      }
    },

    uglify: {
      options: {
        preserveComments: 'some'
      },
      core: {
        src: '<%= concat.bootstrap.dest %>',
        dest: 'dist/js/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js'
      },
      customize: {
        src: configBridge.paths.customizerJs,
        dest: 'docs/assets/js/customize.min.js'
      },
      docsJs: {
        src: configBridge.paths.docsJs,
        dest: 'docs/assets/js/docs.min.js'
      }
    },

    qunit: {
      options: {
        inject: 'js/tests/unit/phantom.js'
      },
      files: 'js/tests/cats.html'
    },

    less: {
      compileCore: {
        options: {
          strictMath: true,
          sourceMap: true,
          outputSourceFiles: true,
          sourceMapURL: '<%= pkg.name %>.css.map',
          sourceMapFilename: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>.css.map'
        },
        src: 'less/bootstrap.less',
        dest: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>.css'
      },
      compileTheme: {
        options: {
          strictMath: true,
          sourceMap: true,
          outputSourceFiles: true,
          sourceMapURL: '<%= pkg.name %>-theme.css.map',
          sourceMapFilename: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>-theme.css.map'
        },
        src: 'less/theme.less',
        dest: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>-theme.css'
      }
    },

    autoprefixer: {
      options: {
        browsers: configBridge.config.autoprefixerBrowsers
      },
      core: {
        options: {
          map: true
        },
        src: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>.css'
      },
      theme: {
        options: {
          map: true
        },
        src: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>-theme.css'
      },
      docs: {
        src: 'docs/assets/css/src/docs.css'
      },
      examples: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'docs/examples/',
        src: ['**/*.css'],
        dest: 'docs/examples/'
      }
    },

    csslint: {
      options: {
        csslintrc: 'less/.csslintrc'
      },
      dist: [
        'dist/css/bootstrap.css',
        'dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css'
      ],
      examples: [
        'docs/examples/**/*.css'
      ],
      docs: {
        options: {
          ids: false,
          'overqualified-elements': false
        },
        src: 'docs/assets/css/src/docs.css'
      }
    },

    cssmin: {
      options: {
        compatibility: 'ie8',
        keepSpecialComments: '*',
        advanced: false
      },
      minifyCore: {
        src: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>.css',
        dest: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>.min.css'
      },
      minifyTheme: {
        src: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>-theme.css',
        dest: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>-theme.min.css'
      },
      docs: {
        src: [
          'docs/assets/css/src/docs.css',
          'docs/assets/css/src/pygments-manni.css'
        ],
        dest: 'docs/assets/css/docs.min.css'
      }
    },

    usebanner: {
      options: {
        position: 'top',
        banner: '<%= banner %>'
      },
      files: {
        src: 'dist/css/*.css'
      }
    },

    csscomb: {
      options: {
        config: 'less/.csscomb.json'
      },
      dist: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'dist/css/',
        src: ['*.css', '!*.min.css'],
        dest: 'dist/css/'
      },
      examples: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'docs/examples/',
        src: '**/*.css',
        dest: 'docs/examples/'
      },
      docs: {
        src: 'docs/assets/css/src/docs.css',
        dest: 'docs/assets/css/src/docs.css'
      }
    },

    copy: {
      fonts: {
        src: 'fonts/*',
        dest: 'dist/'
      },
      docs: {
        src: 'dist/*/*',
        dest: 'docs/'
      }
    },

    connect: {
      server: {
        options: {
          port: 3000,
          base: '.'
        }
      }
    },

    jekyll: {
      options: {
        config: '_config.yml'
      },
      docs: {},
      github: {
        options: {
          raw: 'github: true'
        }
      }
    },

    jade: {
      options: {
        pretty: true,
        data: getLessVarsData
      },
      customizerVars: {
        src: 'docs/_jade/customizer-variables.jade',
        dest: 'docs/_includes/customizer-variables.html'
      },
      customizerNav: {
        src: 'docs/_jade/customizer-nav.jade',
        dest: 'docs/_includes/nav/customize.html'
      }
    },

    validation: {
      options: {
        charset: 'utf-8',
        doctype: 'HTML5',
        failHard: true,
        reset: true,
        relaxerror: [
          'Element img is missing required attribute src.',
          'Attribute autocomplete not allowed on element input at this point.',
          'Attribute autocomplete not allowed on element button at this point.',
          'Bad value separator for attribute role on element li.'
        ]
      },
      files: {
        src: '_gh_pages/**/*.html'
      }
    },

    watch: {
      src: {
        files: '<%= jshint.core.src %>',
        tasks: ['jshint:src', 'qunit', 'concat']
      },
      test: {
        files: '<%= jshint.test.src %>',
        tasks: ['jshint:test', 'qunit']
      },
      less: {
        files: 'less/**/*.less',
        tasks: 'less'
      }
    },

    sed: {
      versionNumber: {
        pattern: (function () {
          var old = grunt.option('oldver');
          return old ? RegExp.quote(old) : old;
        })(),
        replacement: grunt.option('newver'),
        recursive: true
      }
    },

    'saucelabs-qunit': {
      all: {
        options: {
          build: process.env.TRAVIS_JOB_ID,
          throttled: 10,
          maxRetries: 3,
          maxPollRetries: 4,
          urls: ['http://127.0.0.1:3000/js/tests/cats.html'],
          browsers: grunt.file.readYAML('grunt/sauce_browsers.yml')
        }
      }
    },

    exec: {
      npmUpdate: {
        command: 'npm update'
      }
    },

    compress: {
      main: {
        options: {
          archive: 'bootstrap-<%= pkg.version %>-dist.zip',
          mode: 'zip',
          level: 9,
          pretty: true
        },
        files: [
          {
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'dist/',
            src: ['**'],
            dest: 'bootstrap-<%= pkg.version %>-dist'
          }
        ]
      }
    }

  });


  // These plugins provide necessary tasks.
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt, { scope: 'devDependencies' });
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Docs HTML validation task
  grunt.registerTask('validate-html', ['jekyll:docs', 'validation']);

  var runSubset = function (subset) {
    return !process.env.TWBS_TEST || process.env.TWBS_TEST === subset;
  };
  var isUndefOrNonZero = function (val) {
    return val === undefined || val !== '0';
  };

  // Test task.
  var testSubtasks = [];
  // Skip core tests if running a different subset of the test suite
  if (runSubset('core') &&
      // Skip core tests if this is a Savage build
      process.env.TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG !== 'twbs-savage/bootstrap') {
    testSubtasks = testSubtasks.concat(['dist-css', 'dist-js', 'csslint:dist', 'test-js', 'docs']);
  }
  // Skip HTML validation if running a different subset of the test suite
  if (runSubset('validate-html') &&
      // Skip HTML5 validator on Travis when [skip validator] is in the commit message
      isUndefOrNonZero(process.env.TWBS_DO_VALIDATOR)) {
    testSubtasks.push('validate-html');
  }
  // Only run Sauce Labs tests if there's a Sauce access key
  if (typeof process.env.SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY !== 'undefined' &&
      // Skip Sauce if running a different subset of the test suite
      runSubset('sauce-js-unit') &&
      // Skip Sauce on Travis when [skip sauce] is in the commit message
      isUndefOrNonZero(process.env.TWBS_DO_SAUCE)) {
    testSubtasks.push('connect');
    testSubtasks.push('saucelabs-qunit');
  }
  grunt.registerTask('test', testSubtasks);
  grunt.registerTask('test-js', ['jshint:core', 'jshint:test', 'jshint:grunt', 'jscs:core', 'jscs:test', 'jscs:grunt', 'qunit']);

  // JS distribution task.
  grunt.registerTask('dist-js', ['concat', 'uglify:core', 'commonjs']);

  // CSS distribution task.
  grunt.registerTask('less-compile', ['less:compileCore', 'less:compileTheme']);
  grunt.registerTask('dist-css', ['less-compile', 'autoprefixer:core', 'autoprefixer:theme', 'usebanner', 'csscomb:dist', 'cssmin:minifyCore', 'cssmin:minifyTheme']);

  // Full distribution task.
  grunt.registerTask('dist', ['clean:dist', 'dist-css', 'copy:fonts', 'dist-js']);

  // Default task.
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean:dist', 'copy:fonts', 'test']);

  // Version numbering task.
  // grunt change-version-number --oldver=A.B.C --newver=X.Y.Z
  // This can be overzealous, so its changes should always be manually reviewed!
  grunt.registerTask('change-version-number', 'sed');

  grunt.registerTask('build-glyphicons-data', function () { generateGlyphiconsData.call(this, grunt); });

  // task for building customizer
  grunt.registerTask('build-customizer', ['build-customizer-html', 'build-raw-files']);
  grunt.registerTask('build-customizer-html', 'jade');
  grunt.registerTask('build-raw-files', 'Add scripts/less files to customizer.', function () {
    var banner = grunt.template.process('<%= banner %>');
    generateRawFiles(grunt, banner);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('commonjs', 'Generate CommonJS entrypoint module in dist dir.', function () {
    var srcFiles = grunt.config.get('concat.bootstrap.src');
    var destFilepath = 'dist/js/npm.js';
    generateCommonJSModule(grunt, srcFiles, destFilepath);
  });

  // Docs task.
  grunt.registerTask('docs-css', ['autoprefixer:docs', 'autoprefixer:examples', 'csscomb:docs', 'csscomb:examples', 'cssmin:docs']);
  grunt.registerTask('lint-docs-css', ['csslint:docs', 'csslint:examples']);
  grunt.registerTask('docs-js', ['uglify:docsJs', 'uglify:customize']);
  grunt.registerTask('lint-docs-js', ['jshint:assets', 'jscs:assets']);
  grunt.registerTask('docs', ['docs-css', 'lint-docs-css', 'docs-js', 'lint-docs-js', 'clean:docs', 'copy:docs', 'build-glyphicons-data', 'build-customizer']);

  grunt.registerTask('prep-release', ['jekyll:github', 'compress']);

  // Task for updating the cached npm packages used by the Travis build (which are controlled by test-infra/npm-shrinkwrap.json).
  // This task should be run and the updated file should be committed whenever Bootstrap's dependencies change.
  grunt.registerTask('update-shrinkwrap', ['exec:npmUpdate', '_update-shrinkwrap']);
  grunt.registerTask('_update-shrinkwrap', function () {
    var done = this.async();
    npmShrinkwrap({ dev: true, dirname: __dirname }, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        grunt.fail.warn(err);
      }
      var dest = 'test-infra/npm-shrinkwrap.json';
      fs.renameSync('npm-shrinkwrap.json', dest);
      grunt.log.writeln('File ' + dest.cyan + ' updated.');
      done();
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: What is `<!-- bower:js --`> supposed to be doing and what plugin handles that? I'd personally list my bower components in the Grunt file and concat them into a single file, or if you prefer to list them in the HTML, wrap them in `<!-- build:remove -->` instead.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, this is how I've always seen it done, so I've gone with it. I'd like to list each in the HTML file to have them build together. Why would I use <!-- build:remove -->? Cheers

Comment: Okay, have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783199/yeoman-angular-generator-generated-index-html

Comment: @goodpixels thanks! will try tonight and let you know if it solves! :)